# Pattern for injecting plugin options into Hapi route handlers defined in separate files

Tags: design-patterns, plugins, routes, hapi.js

I am developing my Hapi app plugin and my routes are kept in a separate file to the file doing the plugin `server.route` call. Moreover the handlers for those routes are also in separate files. e.g.

```
- plugin.js
- routes.js
- handlers/
    - route1.js
    - route2.js
```

`plugin.js` is something like ....

```
const routes = require('./routes.js')
...
server.route(routes)
```

`routes.js` is something like ...

```
module.exports = [
  { 
    method: 'GET', 
    path: '/route1', 
    handler: require('./handlers/route1')
  },
  ...
]
```

and the handler files export functions with signature `(request, h)`.

My route handlers (and beyond) need access to the options passed in at plugin registration but all they have access to is `(request, h)`

I can wrap the route definitions and each of the route handlers with functions that bring `options` into scope but this feels like defining conventions and folklore around how projects are structured and also I feel like it may cause problems with Javascript scoping/closure weirdness.

Is there a common Hapi library/pattern for allowing me to inject the plugin options into the route handlers e.g. allowing for a signature like `(request, h, options)` in a clean or well defined way?

Comment: You can always use `server.decorate` to expose variables to handlers via plugins. ie `server.decorate('server', "key", "val");` then in route you can access via: `request.server.key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that plugin options are available on the toolkit object as follows ...

```
h.realm.pluginOptions
```